# magento1.9, how to speed up TTFB

Tags: magento-1.9, pagespeed

answer TTFB I expect 10 to 20 seconds of time
I can’t understand why.
Tell me how to improve it.

here is a screenshot `top` command
[image]

Answer (score 0):

install Aoe_profiler
https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler

> Aoe_Profiler is a drop-in replacement for the Varien_Profiler. It can
>   be activated in the configuration and doesn’t require you to change
>   any core files. It captures all data and also records its hierarchal
>   information and displays everything in a nice way.

[image]

you will see magento issues